# Browser being blocked (forbidden) behind proxy

Tags: ssl, proxy, load-balancing, http-status-code-403

I have 2 servers behind a Load Balancer. This LB has SSL configured on it.
Almost 50 different clients are able to connect to my website successfully, except 1 client which received a Forbidden (403) message from the browser.

After some investigation with him, I discovered he is behind a proxy server.

I suggested he assign my domain to bypass proxy, but he argued that it would exploit his system.

I could not figure out anyway to fix this problem yet.

What solutions might there be? Or even if my suggestion to him (to put my domain to bypass proxy) is even correct?

The Website is: [Arke](https://www.arkemessenger.com/)

Comment: If the 403 is from the proxy because access to your site is restricted by some companies security policy there is nothing you can do about. If the reason for the 403 is different then please provide more details.

Comment: I do believe the problem is on the client end. But before I tell him that the problem is on his end, I want to make sure of this. Although, I never had a problem with anyone connecting from anywhere before. the site is [Arke](https://www.arkemessenger.com/). Thanks @SteffenUllrich

Comment: I don't see any strange thing with this site, so I think that the client has just a very restrictive proxy. Would be interesting to know which kind of proxy and if the client has problems accessing other sites too. Also it would be useful to get the details of the 403, i.e. there might be some actual error message with more details for the blocking instead of only the 403 status code.

Answer (score 1):

His proxy is denying your server. Likely, the person who setup his proxy/VPN server has defined some kinda of blacklist. Its not unheard of blocking whole geo-regions or IP Blocks.

I would tell your client to get a new proxy or accept your help of assigning your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it had nothing to do with blocking my IP or Domains. Magically, the next day it work on its own. Weird!

I assumed something bugged on his end.
Maybe clearing cache, cookies and such stuff would've helped.

Just though of answering my own question might help someone.

Thanks all